# Why i can't put string into a field which is something that extends Object

Tags: java

I have a map like the one below

```
final Map<String, ? extends Object> map
```

Can anyone tell me why this operation is not possible..?

```
productMap.put("min", String.valueof(34));
```

What should be the turnaround...

Comment: because it doesn't have to be a string?!

Comment: @Saurabh, it has to be a `? extends Object`, a very specific thing which you don't have any information about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've told the compiler that the map values will be some specific subtype of Object. ? could be anything -- you could do:

```
Map<String,? extends Object> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

So String might be invalid.

You probably want the simpler Map which does allow any value.

Or you can "cheat" and do a cast which hides the generic type:

```
((Map)productMap).put("min", String.valueof(34));
```

But that trick is not best practice & to be used sparingly if at all.

Answer (score 4):

You can't add any object to a Map because the compiler knows the value is some class which extends Object, but doesn't know which one.

```
Map<String, ? extends Object> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
Object val = map.get("min"); // this is ok.
map.put("min", Integer.toString(34)); // not allowed.
```

Instead you can use

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Object val = map.get("min"); // this is ok.
map.put("min", Integer.toString(34)); // is ok.
```

Answer (score 3):

The wildcard provides flexibility (you can now assign a `HashMap<String, String>` or a `HashMap<String, Integer>` to `map`) in exchange for a condition: you cannot write to `map`, because it doesn't know what the actual class of the values will be.

See [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) for a good tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

By declaring the map as `Map<String, ? extends Object>`, you state that the second type is "anything which inherits from object". This is equivalent to declaring the map as `Map<String, ?>`. This declaration enables assignments like

```
final Map<String, ? extends Object> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

I think this example makes it clear why the compiler forbids inserting strings into the map: The value type is unspecified in the declaration.